# Every collection of 5 subsets of size 6 drawn from $\{1, 2, . . . , 15\}$, at least two of the subsets must intersect in at least two points.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Theorem:

Suppose that $A_1, . . . , A_k$ is a collection of $k ≥ 2$ sets. Show that (using induction),

$$\big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i \big| \ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \big|A_i| - \sum\limits_{\{i,j\}} \big|A_i \cap A_j \big| $$

where the second term on the right sums over all subsets of [k] of size 2.

Question:

Deduce that in every collection of 5 subsets of size 6 drawn from $\{1, 2, . . . , 15\}$,
at least two of the subsets must intersect in at least two points.

What I've tried:

Let $|I| = 6$ and $i$ be one of 5 subsets s.t.

$$\big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i \big| = \sum_{0 \neq I \subseteq [k]}(-1)^{6 + 1} \big| \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \big|$$

Since, 6 does not divide 15,

$$\big| \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \big| = 0$$

$$\implies \big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i \big| = 0$$

Since, RHS of the inequality cannot be negative as

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \big|A_i| > \sum\limits_{\{i,j\}} \big|A_i \cap A_j \big|$$

We are left with,

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \big|A_i| - \sum\limits_{\{i,j\}} \big|A_i \cap A_j \big| = 0$$

And going back to the fact that $\frac{15}{6} = \frac{5}{2}$ each subject must contain at-least two common elements with another subset.

Is my proof correct? - I think I may be over thinking it...

Comment: A typo:  Let $|I|=6$ should be let the $A_i$ be subsets of $[15]$ with $|A_i|=6$.  Then on the next line, we are not given that the intersection of all the subsets is empty, the fact that $6$ does not divide $15$ does not matter, and the implication can be false.  You could have the whole intersection be $0$ and have all $15$ elements in the union.

Comment: Is my proof correct now?: Since $\big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i \big| \ge 30 - \sum\limits_{\{i,j\}} \big|A_i \cap A_j \big| $ and $\big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i \big| < 15$

Comment: The last inequality should be $\le$ and you don't explicitly say that each element of the sum is at most $1$ by the problem assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the theorem you quote.  The union on the left is no larger than $15$.  The first sum on the right is $30$ and there are $10$ items in the second sum on the right.  If each item is of size $1$ the right is $20$, a contradiction.